# What is the (kind of) inverse operation to Java's Stream.flatMap()?

Tags: java, java-stream

The `Stream.flatMap()` operation transforms a stream of

```
a, b, c
```

into a stream that contains zero or more elements for each input element, e.g.

```
a1, a2, c1, c2, c3
```

Is there the opposite operations that batches up a few elements into one new one?

- It is not .reduce(), because this produces only one result
- It is not collect(), because this only fills a container (afaiu)
- It is not forEach(), because this has returns just `void` and works with side effects

Does it exist? can I simulate it in any way?

Comment: What return type are you looking for?

Comment: Stream<X> goes in, Stream<Y> comes out where Y is some combination of Xes. In principle the whole thing is very similar to collect(), except it would really keep "streaming", not first collecting and then streaming the result: as @Lino's answer.

Comment: You want `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I figured out that `flatMap` is its own "inverse" so to say. I oversaw that `flatMap` not necessarily increases the number of elements. It may also decrease the number of elements by emitting an empty stream for some of the elements. To implement a group-by operation, the function called by `flatMap` needs minimal internal state, namely the most recent element. It either returns an empty stream or, at the end of a group, it returns the reduced-to group representative.

Here is a quick implementation where `groupBorder` must return `true` if the two elements passed in do not belong to the same group, i.e. between them is the group border. The `combiner` is the group function that combines, for example (1,a), (1,a), (1,a) into (3,a), given that your group elements are, tuples (int, string).

```
public class GroupBy<X> implements Function<X, Stream<X>>{

  private final BiPredicate<X, X> groupBorder;
  private final BinaryOperator<X> combiner;
  private X latest = null;

  public GroupBy(BiPredicate <X, X> groupBorder,
                 BinaryOperator<X> combiner) {
    this.groupBorder = groupBorder;
    this.combiner = combiner;
  }

  @Override
  public Stream<X> apply(X elem) {
    // TODO: add test on end marker as additonal parameter for constructor
    if (elem==null) {
      return latest==null ? Stream.empty() : Stream.of(latest);
    }
    if (latest==null) {
      latest = elem;
      return Stream.empty();
    }
    if (groupBorder.test(latest, elem)) {
      Stream<X> result = Stream.of(latest);
      latest = elem;
      return result;
    }
    latest = combiner.apply(latest,  elem);
    return Stream.empty();
  }
}
```

There is one caveat though: to ship the last group of the whole stream, an end marker must be stuck as the last element into the stream. The above code assumes it is `null`, but an additional end-marker-tester could be added.

I could not come up with a solution that does not rely on the end marker.

Further I did not also convert between incoming and outgoing elements. For a unique-operation, this would just work. For a count-operation, a previous step would have to map individual elements to a counting object.

Comment: What is the practical use of this functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `collapse` in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of("a1", "a2", "c1", "c2", "c3").collapse((a, b) -> a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0))
    .map(e -> e.substring(0, 1)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or [my fork](https://github.com/landawn/streamex) with more function: `groupBy`, `split`, `sliding`...

```
StreamEx.of("a1", "a2", "c1", "c2", "c3").collapse((a, b) -> a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0))
.map(e -> e.substring(0, 1)).forEach(System.out::println);
// a
// c

StreamEx.of("a1", "a2", "c1", "c2", "c3").splitToList(2).forEach(System.out::println);
// [a1, a2]
// [c1, c2]
// [c3]

StreamEx.of("a1", "a2", "c1", "c2", "c3").groupBy(e -> e.charAt(0))
.forEach(System.out::println);
// a=[a1, a2]
// c=[c1, c2, c3]
```

Comment: Does the StreamEx groupBy method avoid collecting all elements in memory before grouping them?

Comment: It does. you can verify it by adding peek before collapse: stream.peek(System.out::println).collapse(...)

Comment: This helped a lot, added another answer for this based on SteamEx. Appreciate taking the time to add this, best answer here imo - memory efficient, maintained and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can *hack* your way around. See the following example:

```
Stream<List<String>> stream = Stream.of("Cat", "Dog", "Whale", "Mouse")
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
       Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> a.length() > 3),
       map -> Stream.of(map.get(true), map.get(false))
    ));
```

Comment: :-) indeed a hack.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(n -> IntStream.of(n, n / 2, n / 3))
            .reduce(IntStream.empty(), IntStream::concat)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

As you see elements are mapped to Streams too, and then concatenated into one large stream.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this or cannot do the transfer, but this seems to assume that I can generate a2, a3 and a4 when I see a1. But this is not the case. Some arbitrary elements come along and I want to batch them up.

Comment: @Harald I understand: editing of a sub-range of several streamed elements, altering the stream. Like data filters in piped I/O / ... . Not something that Stream is good for I think.

Answer (score 1):

Helped mostly by the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) answer above by [user_3380739](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3380739/user-3380739), you can use `groupRuns` [docs here](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns(java.util.function.BiPredicate))

```
StreamEx.of("a1", "a2", "c1", "c2", "c3").groupRuns( t, u -> t.charAt(0) == u.charAt(0) )
.forEach(System.out::println);

// a=[a1, a2]
// c=[c1, c2, c3]
```

Comment: `groupRuns` stops on first null element. If you need nulls, `com.google.mu.util.stream.MoreStreams.groupConsecutive` may be a better alternative. https://google.github.io/mug/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
interface OptionalBinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T, T, Optional<T>> {
  static <T> OptionalBinaryOperator<T> of(BinaryOperator<T> binaryOperator,
          BiPredicate<T, T> biPredicate) {
    return (t1, t2) -> biPredicate.test(t1, t2)
            ? Optional.of(binaryOperator.apply(t1, t2))
            : Optional.empty();
  }
}

class StreamUtils {
  public static <T> Stream<T> reducePartially(Stream<T> stream,
          OptionalBinaryOperator<T> conditionalAccumulator) {
    Stream.Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();
    stream.reduce((t1, t2) -> conditionalAccumulator.apply(t1, t2).orElseGet(() -> {
      builder.add(t1);
      return t2;
    })).ifPresent(builder::add);
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I did not have the time to make it lazy, but it can be done by writing a custom `Spliterator` delegating to `stream.spliterator()` that would follow the logic above (instead of utilizing `stream.reduce()`, which is a terminal operation).

---

PS. I just realized you wanted `<T,U>` conversion, and I wrote about `<T,T>` conversion. If you can first map from `T` to `U`, and then use the function above, then that's it (even if it's suboptimal).

If it's something more complex, the kind of condition for reducing/merging would need to be defined before proposing an API (e.g. `Predicate<T>`, `BiPredicate<T,T>`, `BiPredicate<U,T>`, or maybe even `Predicate<List<T>>`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit like StreamEx, you could implement the Spliterator manually.  For example,

```
collectByTwos(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4), (x, y) -> String.format("%d%d", x, y))
```

... returns a stream of "12", "34" using the code below:

```
public static <X,Y> Stream<Y> collectByTwos(Stream<X> inStream, BiFunction<X,X,Y> mapping) {
    Spliterator<X> origSpliterator = inStream.spliterator();
    Iterator<X> origIterator = Spliterators.iterator(origSpliterator);

    boolean isParallel = inStream.isParallel();
    long newSizeEst = (origSpliterator.estimateSize() + 1) / 2;

    Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<Y> lCombinedSpliterator =
            new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<>(newSizeEst, origSpliterator.characteristics()) {
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Y> action) {
            if (! origIterator.hasNext()) {
                return false;
            }
            X lNext1 = origIterator.next();
            if (! origIterator.hasNext()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Trailing elements of the stream would be ignored.");
            }
            X lNext2 = origIterator.next();
            action.accept(mapping.apply(lNext1, lNext2));
            return true;
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(lCombinedSpliterator, isParallel)
            .onClose(inStream::close);
}
```

(I think this may likely be incorrect for parallel streams.)