# Split a List and then sort

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I want the opposite of `flatMap`. I have the code below:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "C", "B", "AA", "BB", "CC");
Stream<String> stream = list.stream();
Collection<List<String>> val = stream.sorted().collect(groupingBy(String::length)).values();
System.out.println("Values " + val);
```

This does work but the type is `Collection<List<String>>`. How do I make it `List<List<String>>`?

I can iterate through the `Collection` or use `new Arraylist()`. I'm looking for something like `Arrays.asList` which would be more concise and immutable.

If I cast I get `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Also this will sort the whole list and then do the grouping.
Is there a way to group first and then sort the smaller lists which would be more efficient.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50876963

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `List<List<String>>`? Are you planning to access the outer list by index?

Comment: Additionally, could the input list have duplicate elements as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could stream over the values and then collect to a list:

```
 List<List<String>> values = list.stream()
                .sorted()
                .collect(groupingBy(String::length))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .collect(toList());
```

But the better approach would be to pass the result to the `ArrayList` constructor as in:

```
List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
              .sorted().collect(groupingBy(String::length)).values());
```

if you want to sort after grouping then you can do:

```
List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(String::length))
                .values());            
values.forEach(Collections::sort);
```